# DatetimeParseError in Redshift query using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-redshift, node-modules, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'd been trying to get this API to work. I'm successfully able to pass values for companyID, but the same method is not working for dateID.

I have tried declaring it as both:

```
var dateID = 20190610;
var dateID = "20190610";
```

And in the query I have tried both:

```
'${dateID}'
${dateID}
```

I have tried combination of above 4. Nothing seems to work for me. While if 20190610 is passed directly in the query, It works. Any inputs would be appreciated.

```
app.post("/abcd", (req, res) => {
    console.log("test");
    var companyID = "56210";
    var dateID = 20190610;
    redshiftClient.connect(function (err) {
        redshiftClient.query(
            "select company_id as COMPANY,user_id as USERNAME,label as Associate,original_timestamp as Login_Time from sample.account_operation where company_id in ('${companyID}') and label like 'login' and DATE(original_timestamp)>= ('${dateID}') and user_id not like '%@sample%'",
            function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                    redshiftClient.close();
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: change>= ('${dateID}') to >='${dateID}'

Answer (score 0):

change

```
>= ('${dateID}')
```

to

```
>='${dateID}'
```